# jquery ajax not adding <link> in <head> tags in IE

Tags: jquery

I am loading a page via AJAX and putting it in a DIV. Including HTML tags and all. No browser seems to be worried about that, except for the fact that the `<head>` elements never load in IE, but do so in FF.

Is it possible to let the elements in `<head>` to load as well, or do I have to put them in the body?

This includes `<title>` and `<link>`. But the `<style>` element works fine. So I can't load my external stylesheets with my Ajax. Is there a way, or do I have to put it in the body?

Thanks in advance.

Code example:

```
// page to load
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{$cssLink}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> // doesn't load
    <style type="text/css">
    /* CSS bla does work*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testPage_content" class="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the ajax call I am making, if you would need that in your answer.

```
// ask for the page
$.ajax(
{
    url: "Scripts/loader.php",  
    type: "GET",        
    data: data, // created above this call
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) 
    {               
        //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
        $('#content').html(html);       

        // only use fading if opacity is supported          
        if($.support.opacity)
        {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('#content').fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your page which make the call is in XHTML? In this case, the `link` tag must be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should use an `<iframe>` element to load a "complete" website (means with `<html>, <body> and <head>` tags. It's 100% invalid markup otherwise.

I meantioned it would be nasty work to strip, but.. woh maybe not that nasty:

```
success: function (html) 
{               
    //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
    var stripped = $(html),
        head     = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement;

    stripped.find('head').contents().each(function(index, node) {
        if(node.nodeType !== 3) {
           node.setAttribute('data-insertID', 'foobar');
           head.appendChild(node, head.firstChild);
        }
    });

    $('#content').html(stripped.find('body').contents());       

    // only use fading if opacity is supported          
    if($.support.opacity)
    {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#content').fadeIn();
    }
}
```

Delete with:

```
$('head').find('[data-insertID]').remove();
```

This would grab all nodes from the `head section` of your received site and put it into your actuall website. After that it gets all nodes from the `<body>` tag and puts those into your div.. should work, let me know :)

Comment: @jAndy Are you serious? Everyone said: don't use iFrame! So I did a jQuery.history plugin and used a `DIV` instead.

Comment: I agree with jAndy on the issue of loading a complete page. <link> elements need to appear in the <head> of a document. Check the "Tips and notes" section from: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_link.asp In the case you're suggesting you get 2 head elements on the same page which is not standards-compliant.

Comment: @Marnix: I am. If you really want to put it into a `div`, you should strip any of the above mentioned tags. This would be pretty nasty work since you would have to take care of all information you want to keep...

Comment: @jAndy The solution looks nice. But I will have to keep track of deleting it as well. What attribute can I use to keep track of my garbage collection? rel is full of course...

Comment: @Marnix: ok if want to delete it again it is going to become nasty :)

Comment: @Razvan Caliman : http://w3fools.com `link` element in `body` works in IE7 and 8. (IDK for 6, but who cares?)

Comment: If you're loading an entire page then the solution isn't Ajax, or iframe, it's a regular link to an entire page!

Comment: @David Dorward: No it's not, because I have a media player that I want to playback all the time. It's so awful if it would just restart every time.

Comment: @jAndy I'm still not convinced of what I should do. I can pick deleting the HTML structure around it. Or I can pick the adding and deleting of the `link` elements.

Comment: Ok, I decided to collect my own garbage. So I append links to the `head` and remove them on leave. I use the `$.data` to store if it is a dynamic one. One thing left: `.append()` clones them to `head`, so I have to give every stylesheet an id?

Comment: @Marnix: If you just need the `<link>` tags, you don't need to use `contents()`. You could just grab them by `var lnks = stripped.find('head').find('link');` and append that to your `<head>`. That way you can keep a reference to that moved nodes. See this example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/TBhxR/1/