# CSS inside a div gets applied only when mouse pointer changes position in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have some jQuery ajax tabs and within one of the tabs I open a link containing a div, some jQuery and a link to a CSS file, ie

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="url_to_css"></link>
<div>
... some code here
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="url_to_javascript"></script>
```

Every browser except IE7 applies the CSS instantly, but IE7 applies it only when the mouse pointer moves.

I fixed it by loading the CSS in the parent div (the one that's loaded before the div that should be loading the css is opened)

Comment: so... uh... have you fixed it or not?

Comment: "I had a problem, but I fixed it before I finished typing my question".

Comment: yeah, sorry, I had some browser issues when I was posting the question, only part of the question was saved in my session :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same linking problem.

At this moment, I am moving my `link` tags into the `head` tag at the moment they are being loaded.

So:

1. OnLoadingTheNewTab
2. Fetch all `link` tags
3. Put the `link` tags inside the `head` tag.
4. add a reference of `$.data(link, 'dynamic', true);`

On every change of the tab, you can go through all your `link` tags in the `head` and check if they where dynamically loaded. If so, delete them again, because the tab was unloaded.

Seems to work pretty fine for me.

Comment: Hm, that's still a workaround. Do we know what the cause of this issue is?

Comment: @eagerMoose: IE7 doesn't support this inline linking. Because it only loads all links it can find at the moment of loading. After that, it is done. See [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759791/jquery-ajax-not-adding-link-in-head-tags-in-ie) here.